# Switch every pair of characters in a string

Tags: python, string, performance, python-2.7

For example, having the string:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

should result in something like this:

```
badcfehgjilknmporqtsvuxwzy
```

How do I even go about it?

I thought of something not very efficient, such as:

```
s = str(range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1))
new_s = ''
for i in xrange(len(s)):
    if i != 0 and i % 2 == 0:
        new_s += '_' + s[i]
    else:
        new_s += s[i]
# Now it should result in a string such as 'ab_cd_ef_...wx_yz'
l = new_s.split('_')
for i in xrange(len(l)):
    l[i] = l[i][::-1]
result = str(l)
```

Is there any better way ? Some way that is more efficient or more general so I could also go about it with 3 letters more easily ?

Comment: Will the length be even always?

Comment: @thefourtheye No**. By the way, the way I posted still works for a string with an uneven length.

Comment: What do you expect the result to be if you want to get 3 characters?

Comment: `it = iter(s);''.join(next(it, '') + c for c in it )` clean and simple IMO.

Comment: @thefourtheye Every three letters reversed.

Comment: @Jack Okay, what should be the output for `abcd`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I would upvote that ... its a cool solution ... not entirely sure its readable to the general population however :P

Comment: @thefourtheye `cbad`, same result as I'd go about it with my piece of code above (`abcd` -> `abc_d` -> `cba_d` -> `cbad`).

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Please post an answer so I could mark it as best for future readers, yours was the quickest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution without using any imports will be to convert string to an iterator and during the iteration fetch the next character by calling next on the iterator:

```
>>> s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
>>> it = iter(s)
>>> ''.join(next(it, '') + c for c in it )
'badcfehgjilknmporqtsvuxwzy'
```

**Timings:**

```
>>> s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" * 10**5
>>> def func_next_no_cache(s):
    it = iter(s)
    return ''.join([next(it, '') + c for c in it])
...
>>> %timeit func_next_no_cache(s)
1 loops, best of 3: 291 ms per loop
```

But the calls to `next` are actually slowing it down because for finding `next` Python has to go to the builtins starting from local scope, let's cache it and try again:

```
>>> def func_next_cache(s, next=next):
    it = iter(s)
    return ''.join([next(it, '') + c for c in it])
...
>>> %timeit func_next_cache(s)
1 loops, best of 3: 241 ms per loop
```

But the fastest solution will be to use `itertools.izip_longest`:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> def func_izip_l(s):
    it = iter(s)
    return "".join([b+a for a, b in  izip_longest(it, it, fillvalue='')])
...
>>> %timeit func_izip_l(s)

1 loops, best of 3: 209 ms per loop
```

@Joran's code is also very close to this one when used with a list instead of generator expression, but it creates two additional strings in memory:

```
>>> %timeit "".join([b+a for a, b in izip_longest(s[::2], s[1::2], fillvalue="")])
1 loops, best of 3: 212 ms per loop
```

---

**Note** that we should always feed a `list` to `str.join` if speed is a concern: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/846892

Comment: The fastest solution. Thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `zip()` function which woud return a list of tuples as `[(b,a), (d,c), ...]` and the applying `.join()` method to both the elements of the tuple and list as well.

```
a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
# a[::2] = "acegikmoqsuwy"
# a[1::2] = "bdfhjlnprtvx"
print "".join("".join(i) for i in zip(a[1::2], a[::2]))
>>> badcfehgjilknmporqtsvuxwzy
```

**EDIT:** To handle the case of odd length strings, as suggested by @Ashwini  and @TigerhawkT3, you may change the code as:

```
print "".join("".join(i) for i in zip(a2, a1)) + a[-1] if len(a)%2 else ''
```

Comment: What about odd length strings?

Comment: Thanks @TigerhawkT3 for improvising the content of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that reaching for regular expressions first is always the best thing to do, but it seems to fit here. Find 2 characters, sub them in reverse order, and continue until you're out of string.

```
import re

>>> s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
>>> re.sub(r'(.)(.)', "\g<2>\g<1>", s)
'badcfehgjilknmporqtsvuxwzy'
```

Easily generalized to other numbers of characters:

```
>>> def swap3(txt):
...    return re.sub(r'(.)(.)(.)', '\g<3>\g<2>\g<1>', txt)
...
>>> swap3(s)
'cbafedihglkjonmrqputsxwvyz'
```

or

```
>>> def parameterizedSwap(txt, numChars):
...    pat = r"(.)" * numChars
...    replace = "".join(["\g<{0}>".format(numChars-i) for i in range(numChars)])
...    return re.sub(pat, replace, txt)
...
>>> parameterizedSwap(s, 5)
'edcbajihgfonmlktsrqpyxwvuz'
```

Comment: agreed that, although chunking and zip is the approach I first though of, regex is easier to read and more extensible.

Comment: yeah thats why I upvoted this ... nice and short and very easy to read (maybe make the 2nd argument optional (.?) to handle odd length strings ?)

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import izip_longest as myzip
"".join(b+a for a,b in myzip(a[::2],a[1::2],fillvalue=""))
```

this is very similar to the other answers just some what more explicit in explaining what it is doing to the reader of the code

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import zip, chain

c1 = [c for i, c in enumerate(s) if i % 2 == 0]
c2 = [c for i, c in enumerate(s) if i % 2 == 1]
''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip(c2,c1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over pairs of characters and joining them with `izip()` is fairly simple, and the handling of odd string lengths can be dealt with by adding a conditional concatenation to the end.

```
from itertools import izip

s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
print ("".join(((pair[1]+pair[0]) for pair in izip(*[iter(s)]*2))) +
            (s[-1] if len(s) % 2 else ''))
```

The same thing can be done a little more succinctly by using `izip_longest()` instead of `izip()`, as @Ashwini suggests in the comment.

```
from itertools import izip_longest

s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
print "".join(((pair[1]+pair[0]) for pair in
                    izip_longest(*[iter(s)]*2, fillvalue='')))
```

Comment: This will also fail for odd length strings. `izip_longest` with `fillvalue=''` will be a general solution here.